# Change Color of H1 when checkbox is checked in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a gender toggle button. But when I try to color the gender icons when checked it is not changing the color. I am trying to do it in CSS. I know how to do it in Javascript, but I am failing to do in CSS.

Here is my Code.

```css
.switch{
   background-color:white;
   width:30vw;
   height:10vw;
   position:absolute;
   border-radius:30vw;
   border:1vw solid #ccc;
   cursor: pointer;
   user-select: none;
   display:inline-block;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.switch::before, .switch::after{
   content:'';
   width:10vw;
   height:10vw;
   background-color:white;
   position:absolute;
   border-radius:50%;
   top:-10%;
   left:-3%;
   transition: all 350ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.95, 0.38, 0.98), background 150ms ease;

}
.switch::before{
   border:1vw solid lightblue;
}
.switch::after{
   background:#FBD3E1;
   border:1vw solid pink;
}
input:checked + .switch:before {
   background: #D3F0FB;
   transform: translateX(165%);
   border:1vw solid pink;
}
input:checked + .female{
   color:pink;
}
input:checked + .male{
   color:lightblue;
}
input:checked + .switch:after {
   background: #D3F0FB;
   transform: translateX(165%);
   border:1vw solid lightblue;
}
.female, .male{
   position:absolute;
   font-weight:lighter;
   color:#ccc;
}
.female{
   z-index:-1;
   top:13%;
   left:2%;
   transform:rotate(180deg);
   font-size:10vw;
}
.male{
   z-index:-1;
   left:87%;
   top:-145%;
   font-size:10vw;
   transform:rotate(-50deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   
   <input id="switch" type="checkbox" hidden>
   <label for="switch" class="switch">
      <h1 class="female">✝</h1>
      <h1 class="male">➜</h1>
   </label>
   
</div>
```

When I click the checkbox the `➜` symbol should change to lightblue, and when I click the checkbox again `+` symbol should change to pink.

I tried using the following code, But it is not working.

```
input:checked + .female{
   color:pink;
}
input:checked + .male{
   color:lightblue;
}
```

Where am I doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: As I see the checkbox doesn't toggle checkbox on click(I mean not `checked`)

Comment: Can you please modify it @לבנימלכה. Thank you

Comment: do you use jquery or only js?

Comment: @לבנימלכה I can do it in Javascript, What I want is pure CSS version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use parent class `switch` also because it is siblings of input and using `+` you can only style to siblings and change color of h1 also when unchecked

```
input + .switch .female{
   color:pink;
}
input:checked + .switch .male{
   color:lightblue;
}
input + .switch .male{
   color:#ccc;
}
input:checked + .switch .female{
   color:#ccc;
}
```

```css
.switch{
   background-color:white;
   width:30vw;
   height:10vw;
   position:absolute;
   border-radius:30vw;
   border:1vw solid #ccc;
   cursor: pointer;
   user-select: none;
   display:inline-block;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.switch::before, .switch::after{
   content:'';
   width:10vw;
   height:10vw;
   background-color:white;
   position:absolute;
   border-radius:50%;
   top:-10%;
   left:-3%;
   transition: all 350ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.95, 0.38, 0.98), background 150ms ease;

}
.switch::before{
   border:1vw solid lightblue;
}
.switch::after{
   background:#FBD3E1;
   border:1vw solid pink;
}
input:checked + .switch:before {
   background: #D3F0FB;
   transform: translateX(165%);
   border:1vw solid pink;
}
input + .switch .female{
   color:pink;
}
input:checked + .switch .male{
   color:lightblue;
}
input + .switch .male{
   color:#ccc;
}
input:checked + .switch .female{
   color:#ccc;
}
input:checked + .switch:after {
   background: #D3F0FB;
   transform: translateX(165%);
   border:1vw solid lightblue;
}
.female, .male{
   position:absolute;
   font-weight:lighter;
   color:#ccc;
}
.female{
   z-index:-1;
   top:13%;
   left:2%;
   transform:rotate(180deg);
   font-size:10vw;
}
.male{
   z-index:-1;
   left:87%;
   top:-145%;
   font-size:10vw;
   transform:rotate(-50deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   
   <input id="switch" type="checkbox" hidden>
   <label for="switch" class="switch">
      <h1 class="female">✝</h1>
      <h1 class="male">➜</h1>
   </label>
   
</div>
```

Comment: using + you can only style to siblings so need to add as parent class

Comment: then what about `~`?

Comment: ~ it is for all siblings and + for nearby siblings

Comment: @chintuyadavsara Welcome Mate